# How to add a change event to specific inputs in dynamic form in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-composition-api

I want to add a change event to two of the inputs in a dynamic form. Currently, the change event triggers with every input. Is there a way to specify that input 'Shared' and 'Recent' will trigger the change event, but not the others?

```
 <v-input
        v-for="item in state.items"
        :key="item.id"
        @change='triggerChange'
      >
 </v-input>
 state: () => ({
  items: [
    { text: 'My Files', id: '1'},
    { text: 'Shared', id: '2' },
    { text: 'Starred', id: '3' },
    { text: 'Recent', id: '4' },
    { text: 'Offline', id: '5' },
    { text: 'Uploads', id: '6' },
    { text: 'Backups', id: '7' },
  ],
})
   const triggerChange = () => {
  <something happens>
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

@change can take a condition based on current item like so:

```js
 <v-input
        v-for="item in state.items"
        :key="item.id"
        @change="item.id =='2' || item.id == '4' ? triggerChange : () => void 0"
 >
```

Comment: ok that makes sense. What does the 'void 0' represent?

Comment: it just means void function (the zero I am not sure how that how I made it work I saw it somewhere and forgot what it mean)

Comment: Also if the function doesn't trigger you may have to call it with triggerChange(item) rather than just triggeChange in my example

Comment: `void 0` evaluates to undefined, you could also write `() => {}`

Comment: yes that is true both would achieve the same purpose (I just remember liking having void in there it looked better to me)

Answer (score 1):

To keep the logic in template minimal, I'd just check this condition inside the event handler:

```
<v-input
        v-for="item in state.items"
        :key="item.id"
        @change='triggerChange(item)'
      >
 </v-input>

// ...

const triggerChange = (item) => {
  if(!(item.id == 2 || item.id == 4)) { return}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a property `enableChange` with a truthy value to the two items for which you want the `triggerChange()` handler to be triggered on the `change` event. You can then exploit short-circuiting evaluation to conditionally bind the event.

```js
<v-input
    v-for="item in state.items"
    :key="item.id"
    @change="item.enableChange && triggerChange"
></v-input>

// ...

items: [
    { text: 'My Files', id: '1'},
    { text: 'Shared', id: '2', enableChange: true },
    { text: 'Starred', id: '3' },
    { text: 'Recent', id: '4', enableChange: true },
    { text: 'Offline', id: '5' },
    { text: 'Uploads', id: '6' },
    { text: 'Backups', id: '7' },
]
```